# matlab gui plot interaction with mouse to show graph x,y

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-gui

i am trying to make GUI app in matlab that plots in UIaxes, and i want to have normal matlab plot function that allows you to click on any point of plot and get x,y values. but for some reason in GUI UIaxes it doesn't work. take a look at images to understand it more.

this is what i  want to get: on hover show gray dot and coordinates and on click make it blue and stick it to point just like in normal plots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S970U.png)

in UIaxes i dont get any of those functionsi just have a normal cursor, i can zoom in out and move around the plot but cant get the positions. does anyone know what might be wrong or what should be added to gui to make it work

Comment: Are you saying that the datatips do not display when your app is compiled? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816932/cannot-select-data-point-in-uifigure-after-compilation) could help.

Comment: yeah datatips not working at all, i`ll give it a try